# Can I use Google Slides to present online in real-time?

Tags: google-slides

Before I go ahead and make my presentation in Google Slides, I want to know if it is possible to present to remote users, in real time, i.e. to run a Webinar. I will be speaking while I present, and can simply dial in to a conference phone call. But I want to be able to transition the slides and have my audience see my transitions in real time.

My slides include videos, which I want to ensure are presented in high definition, so I'm wary of screen-share functionality that transmits my screen over the internet. I would like the slides and videos to be rendered natively on the user's own browser.

Wherever I look online, people allude to this capability, but it's entirely unclear whether it is actually possible or not.

Answer (score -1):

Google Slides has a presentation mode. You can activate it by going to the “View” menu and selecting “Present”.

You can share your screen using any of the meeting softwares (i.e. Webex, Zoom, Teams, etc.).

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking for. Screen sharing is fine, but the question is about letting the conference attendee open the presentation in his/her web browser. There might be situations (e.g. low bandwidth) where this would work better than screen sharing.